# Filling gap between heatsink and case in minicomputer

Tags: cpu, cooling

I just bought an Ollee 52030 - Ultra Mini Range Smart Cloud PC, a fanless minicomputer.  A copper plate appears to be the processor's heat sink. I would like to move heat from the copper plate sink into the metal case for better cooling, and possibly put a fan on the outside of the case.  What would be the best way to get heat to move from the copper to the case, preferably in a way I can slide the board out later if needed?

Image: Showing gap between case and copper plate on the left side of the case.
[image: Showing gap between case and copper plate on the left side of the case.]

[image: Copper plate and case]

Comment: You don't have a *"minicomputer"*.  Those went obsolete before the turn of the century.

Comment: May I ask why you're trying to do this? It seems this computer was clearly designed to be a fanless, low-profile PC without need for user-provided supplemental cooling. Is there some issue you're experiencing?

Comment: Instead of re-architecting your computer, use a cooling pad or the like. But this should not be happening in the first place.

Comment: @StanleyYu because I like cool computers that also last longer.

Answer (score 0):

Thermal compound on copper plate and attach a real heat sink, then drill holes in the case over the heatsink and point a fan at the new heat sink.